# JFreeChart - fixed width for chart

Tags: java, jfreechart, pie-chart

i am using JFreeCharts PiePlot3D (similar to PieChart). I need to use a fixed size, because the diagram is converted into a png and used in a report with limited space.

My problem is that if the legend grows, the actual diagram shrinks down in size until it is almost useless. This seems to be because i have some descriptions in the legend that are very long, if i use only short descriptions everything is fine.

Now i would like to know if there is a way to set a fixed width for the legend-part of the chart? Maybe in combination with some sort of line-wrap? In general i don't like it that the diagram grows and shrinks with different data, is there a way to set the size statically?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were various discussions on the [JFreeChart forum](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3) related to fixed-size plots and/or charts. Currently (up to JFreeChart 10.14) there is no support in JFreeChart for it. However, a [patch](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/patches/236/) was proposed by paradoxoff that adds basic support for this.

hth,
- martin